# How to disable Google One Tap sign-up prompts?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-accounts

I've recently begun seeing common pop-ups on sites on which I do not have an account.

The pop-ups prompt me with my real name and Google sign-in email, which is being provided either by being signed in to Google/Gmail or being signed in to the desktop Chrome browser.

> #### Sign in to example.com with Google
>
> Your Name
> email@example.com
>
> CONTINUE AS NAME
>
> To create your account, Google will share your name, email address, and profile picture with example.com. By continuing, you agree to example.com's privacy policy and terms of service.

The functionality providing this seems to be variously called: "Google [One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/)", "Google [YOLO](https://neerajsinha.com/google-one-tap-yolo/)", "You Only Log-in Once", the GoogleYOLO API for OpenYOLO, "Google One-tap sign-up and automatic sign-in", "Google Account sign-in prompts", "Sign in with Google", "Log in with Google", "Join with Google", "Use your Google Account to sign in to", "No more passwords to remember. Signing in is fast, simple and secure."

> #### One-tap sign-up and automatic sign-in
>
> https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/
>
> You can provide seamless authentication flows to your users with Google's one-tap sign-up and automatic sign-in APIs.
>
> With one-tap sign-up, users are prompted to create an account with a dialog that's inline with your page's content, so they're never taken out of context by a sign-up page. With just one tap, they get a secure, token-based, passwordless account with your service, protected by their Google Account. And, of course, since there's such little sign-up friction, users are much more likely to register.

I frequently see the pop-up, obscuring the content, [when I follow a link to Medium.com](https://medium.com/groww-engineering/all-about-googles-one-tap-sign-in-b8c1c93305d4).

[image: Sign in to medium.com with Google:]

It is also being added to [other random websites across the internet](https://groww.in/explore):

[image: Sign in to WEBSITE with Google:]

---

Large websites using this sign-in method include:

> - Sign in to medium.com with Google
> - Sign in to nytimes.com with Google
> - Sign in to eBay with Google
> - Sign in to Quora with Google
> - Sign in to trulia.com with Google
> - Sign in to Tripadvisor with Google
> - Use Pinterest with Google
> - Use hipmunk.com with Google
> - Create a wayfair.com account with Google
> - [Use your Google Account to sign in to Reddit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN9qF.png)
> - Use your Google Account to sign in to Medium
> - Vimeo - [Log in with Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izq4N.png)

---

I don't object in principle to using my Google account to sign up for a service, but I do not want these pop-ups obscuring the site contents on page load.

This pop-up feels like a "notification" from Chrome, prompting me to use my signed-in Chrome account. It appears to be something I should be able to disable, like [Chrome notifications](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216), in my local copy of my web browser software.

Or, if not a Chrome browser notification, it also feels like something I should be able to disable from my Google account settings.

How do I disable these pop-ups and ensure they are not shown on any website? Settings-type changes preferred over content blockers, if possible.

Comment: It’s not Chrome, that much is certain. They’re actually part of the website.

Comment: These YOLO login prompts are also [vulnerable to clickjacking exploits](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17044518).

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/13860490

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/142394/194684

Comment: The comments above provided some useful background information, but I am curious, what do websites see if you *don't* click sign in with Google? Does the website know I have a Google account and what my name is even if I don't sign in?

Comment: @jrh Great question, also wondering this, if anyone knows

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can disable these prompts from your Google account's Third-party apps & services settings page:

https://myaccount.google.com/connections/settings

Or go into your Google Account Settings and to the Security Tab. Here you will find a section "Your connections to third-party apps & services". Click "See all connections", and then click the gear icon button to go to settings.

> #### Google Account sign-in prompts
>
> Allow Google to offer a faster way to sign in with your Google Account on supported third-party sites

Toggle off "Google Account sign-in prompts" to disable these prompts across the web.  You need to be signed in to your Google account while visiting websites for this setting to work.

[image: Signing in with Google]

Click refresh to make sure the new setting has stuck.

Comment: Thank you! This has been annoying me for so long. I just tested, and I no longer get pop-ups on medium.com, so it seems to work :) Take my up vote

Comment: It does not work for medium.com now.

Comment: +1 This solution worked for me on all sites, including eBay and Medium. Was able to slide the blue google settings slider off and on, then refresh the offending website for immediate results.

Comment: Thank you! I always wonder if Google does this on purpose to annoy users.

Comment: Wowsa, I had to do this in all google accounts before it went away. F***ing entire company is nothing but malware. So powerful it should be called its own style of product: MaaS: Malware As A Service. I wonder when they start selling my GCP logs.

Comment: It's actually very important to test on medium.com (or similar), and disable it for any accounts which show up

Comment: @LnxSlck Google does it on purpose, but not to annoy users. Instead, they're optimizing for the "typical user" -- think of the average person's parents, who want things to "just work" and don't want their identity stolen. Since Google or Microsoft accounts are dramatically more resistant to compromise than most other accounts (forums, etc.), making it safe and simple to sign in with something like Gmail is a net win for security. That was the thinking when this was built.

Comment: Just fyi, this option appears to be completely useless for some users like myself as of 2 months ago, it does absolutely nothing now, it keeps prompting for every single visit on every single website that has this embedded and no amount of closing it will "pause" it on the next visit. Only thing that works is to block it with uBlock, for example.

Comment: Having to constantly being logged in to a Google account in order to prevent the popups are not a viable solution to the problem.

Comment: @Shadow same here. Keep getting this despite disabling the sign-in prompt on all 3 of my Google accounts. Just started happening in the last ~2 months or so.

Comment: This did not work for me and neither did using the uBlock Origin plugin for Firefox.

Comment: I've also started to see the one-click-share-data-you-trusted-to-google on sites as well though I have had the option disabled for awhile now.

Comment: This really ought to work. My slider has been off for years, but I still get my rendering messed up by these dumb popups. Google One Tap is supposedly the culprit, but following that thread leads nowhere.

Answer (score 29):

In your Adblocker, block all content from `smartlock.google.com`. That will be the end of these popups.

This popup is provided by [a Google service](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview) website owners can select to integrate on their websites.

Comment: @pkamb, it also occurs in other browsers (apparently for Google whitelisted domains only, [to mitigate click-jacking](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17044518)) so you'll probably not find a browser setting.

Comment: smartlock.google.com is not enough to block it. You also have to block accounts.google.com. But, once you block accounts.google.com then none of google works. To be clear, some sites use smartlock.google.com, other sites use accounts.google.com

Comment: As of 2020, the following uBlock Origin expression blocks that: accounts.google.com/gsi/iframe/$subdocument

Comment: @gresolio +1 for your answer. It is working!

Comment: @gresolio Please make this an answer. It is the only real solution to the problem described by the OP IMO

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this did (using Ublock filter):  https://superuser.com/a/1773215/142948

Answer (score 3):

> #### Understand One Tap User Experience
>
> https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/features

Google now tells us exactly how to opt-out of One Tap alerts:

> #### Globally Opt Out
>
> Users can opt out One Tap by disabling the **"Google Account sign-in prompts"** flag in the [connected apps](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) page. The opted-out sessions aren't shown in One Tap. If all Google sessions are opted out, One Tap won't display.

They also detail the specifics of when you will see the next One-Tap pop-up after closing one on the same website:

> #### Exponential Cool Down
>
> If a user closes One Tap by tapping the "X" button in the header, for a time period, One Tap won't display for the same website and in the same browser.
>
> The following exponential time periods are used for cool down.
>
> | Consecutive Closing Times | One Tap will be disabled |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2 hours |
> | 2 | 1 day |
> | 3 | 1 week |
> | 4+ | 4 weeks |
>
> The cool down status will be reset after a successful One Tap sign-in.

Comment: I've been closing these things for months, and they continue show up. This functionality is either broken, or no longer works as described by your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for me.

Add this line to your `AdBlock` Chrome extension under custom options:

`accounts.google.com/gsi/*`

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's answer works on medium.com<sup>*</sup> (and probably others) but not in pinterest. That site keeps nagging you on every visit, and uses pop-up elements containing *multiple* 'random' ID strings (so you can't just filter on these). The substring to filter on for blocking the popup with AdBlock Plus seems to be:

```
&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fnl.pinterest.com
```

<sup>* Note that medium.com prompts you only once anyway; your (non-)response is kept in a cookie.</sup>