# How do I disable the Firefox "sign into XXXX with Google" popup?

Tags: firefox, security, login, privacy, internet-security

I've looked around and found ways to do this in Chrome, but how can I disable this in Firefox?

[image: Firefox auto sign-in]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular ui widget. where is it and what are you doing that causes it to display?

Comment: From my understanding this popup is created by JavaScript code from Google. So it is a part of the web site you are viewing. Removing the popup means you have to modify the website and the JavaScript code. If you want to block all scripts from Google you could give NoScript addon a try and try out which hsosts to block JavaSCript from. A more fine granular way would be Greasemonkey addon which allows you to inject JavaScript into the page and thus change the page behavior. Of course that requires JavaScript programming skills and every time Google changes the script this way will break.

Comment: @Robert, interesting.  It only started showing up after upgrading to the latest Firefox version.  Do you have a reference for what Google JS is triggering that popup so I can look at Greasemonkey?

Comment: Do you mean this in your question by any chance? https://superuser.com/questions/1414410/how-to-disable-google-one-tap-sign-up-prompts

Comment: @koddo, Yep, that is the answer!